# How to differentiate between iphone/ipad and macOS/BigSur on an iOS only project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

If you want to build only an iOS app but want it to be able to run on BigSur as well you only need to open a project for iOS only and then can add Mac as deployment in the App settings Deployment Info. This will run on the mac then as well using the iOS app.

But using

```
#if os(iOS)
#else
#endif
```

will not work here because you are only running an iOS app in the first place!

My Question:

How do you differentiate between the two cases of an iOS app on an iPhone/iPad
and an iOS app on MacOS?

Comment: You are talking about Mac Catalyst here, right?

Comment: yes indeed. so the macOS emulator inside the iOS app.

Comment: Then you can use `targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)` the same way you check for the OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
#else
#endif
```